# Metric on $\mathbb{S}^6$ whose curvature operator has a special signature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Does there exist a metric on $\mathbb{S}^6$ whose curvature operator has signature $\left(n_+,n_-\right)=\left(6,9\right)$ everywhere?